# How do i create a line chart in the picture below in streamlit working with src

Tags: python, linechart, streamlit

[Uisng :

```
import src.tools
import src.assets
```

I'm not familiar with using src.tools in streamlit I like to be able to create a similar chart I attached. any way to write this ?]

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tmw9.png)

Data is the first Picture in the screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how to create this line chart with src.tools, but you can definitely build similar plot with altair, for example:

First, let's prepare the data and convert your wide dataframe to a long one:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'month':['Jan-01','Apr-01','Aug-01', 'Sep-01','Oct-01','Nov-01','Dec-01', 'Jan-02','Feb-02','Mar-02','Apr-02','May-02','Jun-02'],
                 'Fuji - Monthly': [2999, 3022, 3920, 3043, 3094, 3166, 2983, 2784, 2982, 3096, 2309, 2394, 3002],
                  'Fuji - 12 Month Average':[3300, 3293, 3290, 3290, 3242, 3230, 3221, 3142, 3121, 3062, 3061, 3020, 2890]})
df.head()
a=df.melt(id_vars=['month'])
a.dtypes
```

and the chart: it consists of several layers

- chart (with lines) - for solid and dashed line.
- dots for monthly data. It's actually a question for improvement how to combine dashes and dots in one chart.
- text - manually generated legend. The one that was generated automatically was without dashes... just 2 solid lines.
- line label - line to show the "hole" in your data between april and august.
- with Text layer you can also add starting and ending poitnt.

the only thing you need to do to show the chart inside streamlit is

import altair as alt
st.altair_chart(final_chart)

```
x_labels=a.month.tolist()

chart=alt.Chart(a).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('month:N', sort=x_labels, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=330), title=""),
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', title="Miles"),
    color=alt.Color("variable", legend=None, scale=alt.Scale(domain=["Fuji - Monthly", "Fuji - 12 Month Average"], range=["darkblue", "darkblue"])),
    strokeDash=alt.condition(
        alt.datum.variable == "Fuji - 12 Month Average",
        alt.value([5, 5]),  # dashed line: 5 pixels  dash + 5 pixels space
        alt.value([0]),  # solid line
    )
).properties(width=600)

dots=alt.Chart(a.loc[a['variable']=="Fuji - Monthly"]).mark_point(filled=True, color="darkblue").encode(
    x=alt.X('month:N', sort=x_labels, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=330), title=""),
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', title="Miles"),
).properties(width=600)


text = alt.Chart(a
).mark_text(x=300, y=360, dx=-25,fontSize=10, color='darkblue',text=' ⎯⎯ Monthly       - -12 Month Average',
).encode()

df_line = pd.DataFrame([
    {'month': "Apr-01", 'value' : 3400}, 
    {'month': "Apr-01", 'value' : 2900}
])

line_label=alt.Chart(df_line).mark_line(color="grey", ).encode(
    x=alt.X('month:N', sort=x_labels, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=330), title=""),
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', title=""), 
)

final_chart=alt.layer(chart, dots, text, line_label).configure_view(
    stroke='transparent').properties(
    title={
        "text":["Pyth Mean Distance Between Lux Exo"],
        
    }
).configure_title(
    #anchor='start',
    fontSize=30,
    subtitleFontSize=10
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=14
)
final_chart
```

[image: altair chart]